# Assign last number of a text file to a variable C++

Tags: c++, variables, fstream

I am doing a program that outputs a list of prime numbers with fstream.

I have this so far:

```
int export_list (int lim = 50)
{
    int x;
    last_in_txt = ????????????; // assigns last number on txt

    ofstream file ("Primes.txt" , ios::app);

    if (file.is_open()) // if it opens correctly
    {
        for (x = last_in_txt ; x < lim ; x++)
        {
            if (check_prime (x)) // returns 1 when x is prime, returns 0 when not
            {
                file<< x << " ";
            }
        }
        cout << "Done!" << endl << pressenter;
        cin.get();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Unable to open file" << endl << pressenter;
        cin.get();
    }
    return(0);
}
```

So, as you can see, this should append a list of prime numbers to Primes.txt, starting with the prime 1234547.

Primes.txt looks like this:

```
2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 (...) 1234543 1234547
```

My question is how do I assign `1234547` (which is the last number of the txt) to the variable `last_in_txt`?

Other (not so important) question:
Should I save the numbers the way I'm currently doing, or should I store each number in a separate line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple way: keep reading and assign until the whole file is read.

For example,

```
int last_in_txt = 0;
{
    ifstream infile("Prime.txt");
    int k;
    while(infile >> k) {
        last_in_txt = k;
    }
}
// Now last_in_txt is assigned properly, and Prime.txt is closed
```

This works well no matter the numbers in `Prime.txt` are separated by space characters (`' '`) or by newline characters (`'\n'`).

Comment: thank you so much :) I'm gonna try this :)but isn't this going to be hard when the file gets huge?
Isn't there any other way? For example, in scheme (lisp dialect) I would use (list tail) to get the last element of the list.

Comment: @HenriqueFerrolho The problem is this is just a file. How many bytes is the last number in the file occupying? Maybe it's a 10000 digit number. You could certainly optimize this if you absolutely need to: You could read a reasonable chunk of text in from the end of the file and then parse it backwards looking for the first whitespace.

Comment: @timrau it still isn't working :/
`int export_list (int lim = 50)
{
 int last_in_txt = 0;
 {
  ifstream infile("Prime.txt");
  int k;
  while(infile >> k)
  { last_in_txt = k; }
 }

 ofstream file ("Primes.txt" , ios::app);
 int x, counter;

 if (file.is_open())
 {
  for (x = last_in_txt , counter = 0 ; counter < lim ; x++ , counter++)
  {
   if (check_prime (x))
   {
    file << x << " ";
   }
  }
  cout << "Done!" << endl << pressenter;
  cin.get();
 }
 else
 {
  cout << "Unable to open file" << endl << pressenter;
  cin.get();
 }
 return(0);
}`

Comment: ups, sorry about the mess above... How can I reply correctly? I'm a nooby

Comment: @HenriqueFerrolho Have you tried debugger to see which part isn't working?

Comment: @timrau nevermind :) got it working :) should I update the question with my final working program? Also, can you link me something about how to use the debugger? I have only worked with DrScheme before and there was a button to debug, but in VS2012 I am not really sure on how to do it... :s

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is that you write using binary format into the text file(using `wb` in `C`). In this case you will know how many bytes does the last number occupy and you will be able to use `seekg` and `tellg` to get it. If you use plain text format you will have to read char by char from the end and this is more error-prone and also slower.

Comment: Why would reading char-by-char be necessary? What's wrong with extracting `int`s with `>>`?

Comment: @Angew I want to avoid reading all file so I suggest reading from its end. In this case I can't see how you can use `>>`

Comment: I've apparently missed the "from the end" bit.